# How does atmospheric pressure remains constant even though we have released 43 billion tons of $\ce{CO2}$ in one year?

Tags: atmosphere, earth-observation, greenhouse-gases, earth-system

I've heard that the concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> has been increased in the air.

It should have increased atmospheric pressure, right?

Comment: CO2 also dissolves in water causing other problems.

Comment: yes but it's a natural process by photosynthesis (phytoplankton and algae). They emit O2 as well.

Comment: unfortunately the acid increase due to CO2 is quicker destructive than natural processes by photosynthesis can compensate see https://www.gbrmpa.gov.au/our-work/threats-to-the-reef/climate-change/ocean-acidification

Comment: True through sublimation as well co2 would be dissolved into seawater. Still with such a very large quantity of co2 being emitted doesn't it affect the pressure. Just curious though!

Comment: I suppose the atmosphere is not constrained like a bottle wall so just increasing the amount of gas would maybe not follow directly Boyle's law even if there was not chemical and biological interaction going on. It is an interesting question. There is a similar question only the volume of the PVT is considered here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/is-volume-of-air-increasing-as-co2-levels-increase?rq=1

Comment: Short and correct answer (apart from everything else in this thread): The amount of CO2 released into the atmosphere is insignificant for the total atmospheric mass, but not negligible for its infrared opacity (CO2 has a very high infrared opacity per unit mass compared to the average atmosphere).

Comment: This question and its answers will be used by conspiracy theorists in 3...2...1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Earth's atmosphere has a mass of about 5.15×10^18 kg or 5.15 Quadrillion Metric tons, CO2 human outputs since start of the Industrial revolution amount to 654 billion tons, or 1/7,800 th of it's overall mass. Also CO2 emissions came from consuming existing atmospheric oxygen. The Carbon that was added using stoichiometric calculations; Only 27% of CO2's mass is carbon so  of the 654 Billion tons of CO2 added since 1850's, only 176.58 billion tons came from added Carbon or 1/29,000th the the Atmospheric mass. Not enough to do anything to adjust overall atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 2):

We have issued around 200 ppm of CO<sub>2</sub>. That means 0,02 % of the atmosphere.

Furthermore the [combustion reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion#Complete) consumes O<sub>2</sub>. Also part of the CO<sub>2</sub> dissolves in the ocean because of [Henry's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law).

The variation of atmospheric pressure due to industrial activity is negligible, much less than 0,02%.

Comment: Time-dependent processes like combustion and dissolution cannot be part of the answer, as the $\rm CO_2$ partial pressure at any given moment is given by its number at that moment.